# C++ Is it possible to build a list of template types?

Tags: c++, templates

So I don't know if this is possible but I've got a setup that looks a little something like:

```
template <class T>
struct Something;

struct Example {
    //not sure how this should be defined
    //I was thinking void*, but I can't use pointers as the 'Something' class moves around the instances
    //and I don't want to have to constantly update the pointers.
    std::vector<?> addedTypes;

    template<typename T>
    void addThing() {
        addedTypes.push_back(T);
        Something<T>::addThing(*this);
    }

    void destroy() {
        for (auto T : addedTypes) {
            Something<T>::removeThing(*this);
        }
    }
};

template <class T>
struct Something {
    static void addThing(Example e) {/*...*/}
    static void removeThing(Example e) {/*...*/}
};
```

Basically I want to know how I could go about making a list of types that have been added to loop so later I can call the static remove function?

Edit: Adding a little more info as suggested by the comments.

This is just for example, its actually an entity component system where "Example" is an entity, and "Something" is a CRTP component. All the logic is stored in the components, aside from an ID and some helper functions in the entity. The only part missing is a way to destroy the components (of various types) from the entity (i can do this already from the components, but without having the types, I'm not sure how to go about this from the entity.

As for the reason static functions are being called in the "Something" class, they interact with other static class members (e.g. `std::vector<T> list`), and do not touch instanced member state.

Comment: `std::any` or `std::variant` maybe?

Comment: @YSC I'll give those a shot

Comment: It might help if you specify what problem you're actually trying to solve. I.e. what do you want to do with this? Maybe you're looking for `std::vector< std::type_info >` ?

Comment: Is the static remove function the only bit you're interested in? Or do you need the vector of types to work for other reasons as well?

Comment: @Useless primarily to use in the remove function, maybe other things down the road though...

Comment: Maybe its' just your example - but wrapping "Something" with "Example" looks pointless since it would be faster and cleaner to just use the "Something" directly.

Comment: @UKMonkey this is just for example, its actually an entity component system where "Example" is an entity, and "Something" is a CRTP component. All the logic is stored in the components, aside from an ID and some helper functions in the entity. The only part missing is a way to destroy the components (of various types) from the entity (i can do this already from the components, but without having the types, I'm not sure how to go about this from the entity.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that `addThing` and `removeThing` are static members of a class, and not free functions?

Comment: @Caleth they interact with other static class members, and do not touch instanced member state.

Comment: `std::vector<std::function<void(Example&)>>` seems to do the job.

Comment: i would suggest you to add your last comment to the question. With type erasure it often matters what you want to do with the objects later on. Erasing the type is relatively easy, but retrieving the type information later on depends on how you want to use the objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not building list of type, but provide a list of "remover".

I use `std::function` here, maybe create `IRemover` would make more sense for you (or simple function pointer is enough):

```
template <class T>
struct Something;

struct Example {
    std::vector<std::function<void(Example&)>> removers;

    template<typename T>
    void addThing() {
        removers.push_back(&Something<T>::removeThing);
        Something<T>::addThing(*this);
    }

    void destroy() {
        for (auto& f : removers) {
            f(*this);
        }
        removers.clear();
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when attempting to run your example: `'std::vector<std::function<void (Example&)>,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back': 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer`, any ideas?

Comment: Check signature of `Something<T>::removeThing`. In your sample, you pass by value, I expect pass by reference.

Comment: I just tried with `static bool removeThing(Entity& entity) {}` in `template <class T>
struct Something;` same problem when changing Entity from value to reference.. :s  Was that the change you were meaning?

Comment: It turns out my function was const, as I had forgotten to remove that since adding the vector, my fault, your code worked perfectly, thank you.